# Move specific column value to first row first

Tags: sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I need to move the Status == 'Processing' to the first row at here. I tried used OrderBy but return SqlExpression error as there is OrderByFields before it. Can anyone help?

```
var inputQuery = db.From<WO>()
                      .Where<WO>(x => x.ProcessDateTime.Substring(5, 2) == "06")
                      .OrderByFields("PRDLine", "-ProcessDateTime");
```

Comment: sample data would make things much more clear here, also, your question does not seems to be about sql-server at all, it looks more like a linq question to me

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `SqlExpression` to `Single` method.

```
var result = db.Single(inputQuery);
```

If you only want first row, add `.Take(1)` after `OrderByFields` so you force `SELECT TOP 1` on SQL query generation.